# How do I delete a draft message (SMS)?

Tags: sms, drafts

I have created a draft message using the standard HTC Desire message application. However I now want to delete the draft.

When I select the thread I see my previous message, and my draft text below. I select "Menu", "...More", and then "Delete" and am warned I am about to delete entire thread. Which is stupid. I want to delete my draft.

How do I delete a draft?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just figured this one out having had the same problem myself (HTC Desire HD, Android 2.2)....

From the "All Messages" view, press the Menu button.  A "Drafts" icon appears (a floppy disk icon) - press that, and it takes you to a view of all your drafts.

Press & hold a draft message to View/Delete or press the Menu button again & select Delete Drafts to go to a view where you can bulk mark the drafts you want to delete.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Brilliant! Well done, after several weeks of scratching my head you have provided the answer. I hope others upvote you too!

Comment: hi i have a same problem too
but i cant' found A "Drafts" icon
i already press the menu button, and i just see compose, delete threads, search, & settings
where's a drafts icon?

please help me

Answer (score 11):

just clear the text of the draft message, and it will automatically disappear

Comment: Actually, no. When I delete the text of the draft, and press "back", then next time I select the thread the draft text is back. -1 for untested answer.

Comment: actually I've been doing it and it always worked.

Comment: What version of Android and manufacturer, Louis Rhys? I am using Android 2.2 on a HTC Sense phone.. that could be the problem..

Comment: Doesn't work for me. 2.2 Desire Z

Comment: I have T-Mobile G2 (USA), which is supposed to be the same hardware as a Desire Z. My SMS app is called "Messaging" (green, square cartoon talking bubble), version 2.3.4 (Gingerbread version). In this version and in Froyo, when I clear the text, "draft" goes away" in the thread display. I have no "drafts" button in my button bar after pressing "menu".

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried pressing and holding on the text of the draft message and then using the context menu to delete that single draft message?

Comment: That's what Louis suggested, and it doesn't work. The draft reappears when you reopen the conversation.

Aaron has it right!